# using PHP global variable

Tags: php

I have a PHP global variable that I fill with a row from a database in the PHP section of my file.

```
global $row;
/* Retrieve each row as an associative array and display the results.*/
 while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
```

when I 'echo'  the $row individual fields the values print out as expected.

```
  echo $row['Cust_Last_Name'].", ".$row['Cust_PRI_Phone_Number']."<br />";
```

When I try to use the individual fields later in the HTML code later in the file nothing is echoed.

```
<label >Name</label>
<?php  global $row; echo  $row['Cust_Last_Name'];    ?>
```

Is there something else that has to be coded for the name to be echoed ?

Thanks,
Bob H

Comment: Ugh, bad use of global (as though there are any good uses).... your while loop populates $row with one record at a time until the end of the recordset is reached whereupon $row will be false after the last fetch fails to retrieve any more records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
global $rows;

while ($row = ...) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

You will have all the rows in the $rows array.

(But try to avoid using global variables.)